# Does setColorFilter affect ONLY src, or src AND background?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-drawable

## NOTE - this question concerns the android:background property.

Confusingly, "background" is also often used to mean simply "the 'background color' of the photo used for the Android: src".

Say I have.

```
<ImageView
  android:src="@drawable/white_foreground_thing"
  android:background="@drawable/some_bg_thing"
  />
```

I'm going to change the **setColorFilter**.

In fact, does that affect **ONLY the "src" - that is to say the foreground**.

Or does it **ALSO affect the background**.?

```
android:background="@drawable/some_bg_thing"
```

In my example, the foreground (ie, the src) is a 40 pixel white dot (so, I'm going to be making "dots of different colors").

But the background is just an ordinary button background, actually with some transparency and so on.

So I want to NOT affect the background; I'll be changing only the "color of the large dot" for different buttons.

Pls note that (a) it's somewhat hard to tell for sure from testing, with the subtleties of setColorFilter and (b) I really couldn't find this in the doco (probably obvious to you Android dudes!)

Further - is the PosterDuff.Mode relevant here? Or is that completely irrelevant?

(Example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/18954101/294884 )

By the way in many situations here is a fantastic solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17756634/294884

(notice the colored dots down the bottom)

But here, I just want to find out whether the hell setColorFilter affects the .background or only the .src

Comment: `is the PosterDuff.Mode relevant here?` Oh, yes, it is. **A lot**. I found this [page](http://ssp.impulsetrain.com/porterduff.html) really enlightening. Please, have a read and discover how the different Porter Duff modes will affect the drawing.

Comment: Now just to be clear .. I mean the actual "BACKGROUND PROPERTY" OF THE IMAGEVIEW.  I don't mean the "background" of the "photo".  (So, imagine the .src is a "photo of a cat with the blue sky as a background".)  I realise you can **use a matrix somehow** to tease out colors when using the filter.  But here, I just mean, does the filter affect simply the **"android:background="@drawable/blah""** aspect of the overall image view ... or, only the src?

Comment: No, only the image you apply the filter on. i.e.: the **src**, in this case. I provided an answer to a similar problem (change the color of an overlaid image over another one) - you might find it interesting: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24289780/2649012)

Comment: Magnficent!  I guess that's the answer .. better post as an answer? (There's no zoop button on this site.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## No, only the image you apply the filter on. i.e.: the src.

---

Now this is how I overlaid a couple of images and changed the color of one of the two.
You can try to set **@drawable/head_xxh** as the **background** of **imgHair** (so, getting rid of one ImageView) and see if it works as expected.

The result is referred to the two separate and overlaid ImageViews.

Just for fun, and curiosity, I tried to make my own implementation of your idea.
After preparing the two following xxhdpi images (480 dpi, so to make them scale well - then I put them in the `/res/drawable-xxhdpi` folder)

Of course, I had to carefully size the images to fit and overlap perfectly.

[image] and a white hair (a copy of yours, made "whitish" - desaturate + play with brightness/contrast) [image]

I made this layout, in which the hair image overlaps the head:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f000"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/head_xxh"
    />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgHair"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/hair_wht_xxh"
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnColor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Random hair color"
        android:onClick="clickHandler"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the code I used:

```
package com.dergolem.abc_2;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Generic
extends Activity
{
    Random rnd = new Random();

    Button btn = null;
    ImageView img = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.hair);

        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgHair);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnColor);
    }

    public void clickHandler(final View v)
    {
        colorize(rnd.nextInt(7));
    }

    private void colorize(final int num)
    {
        int clr = Color.WHITE;
        switch (num)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                clr = Color.RED;
                break;
            }
            case 1:
            {
                clr = Color.GREEN;
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                clr = Color.BLUE;
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                clr = Color.BLACK;
                break;
            }
            case 4:
            {
                clr = Color.CYAN;
                break;
            }
            case 5:
            {
                clr = Color.YELLOW;
                break;
            }
            case 6:
            {
                clr = Color.parseColor("#ff888800");
                break;
            }
        }

        img.setColorFilter(clr, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    }
}
```

And some of the results I got:

[image] [image] [image] [image]

Even if this composition seems like an Andy Wharol's picture, it isn't. It's mine. :)
It seems like the result you are looking for.

**[EDIT]**

I didn't try this new idea, but (with some extra work) you can even change other colors:

- Eyes
- Skin
- Lipstick
- Eye makeup (this would require some patience)

Comment: Wow! You like **CUBITAL** characters! ;)